# Flask App Builder - Post Processing Model View

Tags: python, flask, flask-appbuilder

Is there any way with Flask App builder to add post processing to after the form has been posted? For example, after the add form is submitted, I'd like to modify some of the data that has been sent.

I cannot for the life of me find anything in the docs, and I feel like this should be basic functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by overriding the post_add function. If you want to modify the data before it is sent (which is what I wanted to do) that would be overriding the pre_add function.